# WPF get binding value of a textbox in GridView Column

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am implementing a function to order items in a `ListView` by column value.

Here is a piece of my XAML code :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView4" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRepere}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeDesReperes}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" ContextMenuOpening="ListView4_ContextMenuOpening" SelectionChanged="ListView4_SelectionChanged" Visibility="{Binding Grid4Visible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" >
                <ListView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="Context4">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="Context4MakeLonger" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.MakeLonger}" Click="Make_Longer"/>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="Context4Search" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Search}" Click="Search_Detail"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ListView.View>

                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" x:Name="GridView4">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" Width="50"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding Path=Name}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Nom}" Width="200">

                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.QuantiteUnit}" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Quantite}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.QuantiteTot}" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TotalQuantity}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Profil}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Profil}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Priorite}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Priorite}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Matiere}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Matiere}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GroupeProfil}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.GroupeProfil}" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Longueur}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Longueur}" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Longueur, StringFormat={}{0:#000}}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Weight}" Width="70">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Poids, StringFormat=N2}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Avancement}">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Name="PART_Track"  Height="20" Stroke="black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{Binding RectangleProgression}" Tag="{Binding Name}" MouseMove="mouseOverProgression">
                                        <Rectangle.ToolTip>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ToolTipProgressionTb1}" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=ToolTipProgressionTb2}" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Rectangle.ToolTip>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

When I want to take the value on which binds my column, I use the following formula :

```
string header = ((System.Windows.Data.Binding)headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;
```

This code works very well as much as I define the binding right in `GridViewColumn` (i.e : Profil, Priorite...)

The problem is when inside my Column I have some `CellTemplate`, and a `TextBox` inside, I would like to take the `DisplayMemberBinding` of my `TextBox`.

For column "Longueur", I tried to put binding both in `GridViewColumn`, and in `TextBox`, it solved the problem but I don't think it is a good solution.

How can I do something kind :

```
header = ((System.Windows.Data.Binding)headerClicked.Column.CellTemplate.TextBox.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could retrieve the binding path from the `TextBlock`:

```
DataTemplate cellTemplate = headerClicked.Column.CellTemplate;
Grid grid = cellTemplate.LoadContent() as Grid;
TextBlock textBlock = grid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
string bindingPath = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty).Path.Path;
```